# run Analysis on regular basis - Oracle Business Intelligence (OBIEE)

Tags: oracle, analysis, business-intelligence, obiee

How do I run Analysis on regular basis in Oracle Business Intelligence (OBIEE) ?

Let's say I have phisycal table in repository (select type), it is casheable and cashe is valid during 7 hours. When user runs Analysis it waits about 3 minutes. My need is to run Analysis daily at 8:45 AM so that every next attempt uses cashe during 7 hours.

Comment: How did that work out? By the way, if you want to use agents make sure you have the Enterprise Edition license.

Answer (score 0):

Create an agent ( New / Actionable Intelligence / Agent) and check the Oracle BI Server Cache box in the "Destinations" tab.

Select your analysis (the one that takes 3 minutes) in the "Delivery Content" tab and set the frequency in the "Schedule" tab.

[OBIEE 11g User guide: Creating Agents](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e10544/delivers.htm#autoId7)

Answer (score 0):

`Victor HDC`

`How did that work out?`

Well, it works now with another solution. 
We use Oracle procedure to insert data into Result table in the end of business day. 
Then user just opens Analysis and it returns data from Result table.

BTW, Oracle procedure calculates data not just for current business day, but for last week (in case something has changed in source tables).

We insert data from transaction server into report server using dblink and all calculations are performed at report server (this is used for better performance).

Upd: can't recover my marchello' password, so answered as marchelloUA.